# Unable to cast object of type 'SingleResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

Getting error on calling store procedure in linq to sql, MVC 3. I am just retrieving single integer from SP, like COUNT result for select query.

ERROR:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SingleResult`1[EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.GetUser_PwdResult]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Source Error: 


Line 26:         public ActionResult AfterLogIn(int EmplID, String EmpPwd) 
Line 27:         {
Line 28:             int Num_Rows = Convert.ToInt32(DataContext.GetUser_Pwd(EmplID, EmpPwd));
Line 29:             if (Num_Rows == 1) 
Line 30:             {
```

Code:

```
public ActionResult AfterLogIn(int EmplID, String EmpPwd) 
        {
            int Num_Rows = Convert.ToInt32(DataContext.GetUser_Pwd(EmplID, EmpPwd));
            if (Num_Rows == 1) 
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Logged In";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Log-in Failed";
            }
            return View();
        }
```

SP: This SP i am calling from Code actually,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUser_Pwd
  @EmplID int,
  @EmplPwd varchar(50)

As  
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Declare @No_Rows int
    Select No_Rows= count(*) from HrEmployee where EmplID = @EmplID AND PassWord = @EmplPwd
    Return @No_Rows
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will look on `GetUser_Pwd` method signature, you will see that it returns `ISingleResult<GetUser_PwdResult>`. Thats how Linq To Sql returns data from store procedures -it generates new class which include all fields from result set. Even if you will use stored procedure, which returns data from table mapped to entity in your data model, new `StoredProcedureNameResult` type will be generated with all fields from table.  So, `GetUser_PwdResult` objects will look like:

```
public partial class GetUser_PwdResult
{
    public Nullable<int> No_Rows { get; set; }
}
```

And problem here is that neither this class nor collection of `GetUser_PwdResult` objects is not convertible to integer. So your conversion fails.

Thus you know there will be exactly one returned object in results collection, you can get first item from collection and read its `No_Rows` value:

```
int? Num_Rows = DataContext.GetUser_Pwd(EmplID, EmpPwd).First().No_Rows;
```

Comment: if you could expalin .First and no_rows ? like way of performing

Comment: @Evilrising sure, wait a minute

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext.GetUser_Pwd()` function does not return an `int`, (or something you can cast to an `int`), it returns a `SingleResult`.

Instead of trying to cast it to `int`, you could try to see if it's `null`:

```
var result = DataContext.GetUser_Pwd(EmplID, EmpPwd);
if (result != null) { 
    // logged in
}
```

---

*Edit to reflect updated question:*

Your `SingleResult` should contain the fields selected in your query:

```
var result = DataContext.GetUser_Pwd(EmplID, EmpPwd).First();
if (result.No_Rows == 1) { 
    // logged in
}
```

Comment: Error: Error 6 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.GetUser_PwdResult>' does not contain a definition for 'No_Rows' and no extension method 'No_Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.GetUser_PwdResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You should get the first result of the collection. See the documentation and examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556.aspx